# Insert Smiley(emotions) in JTextArea using JButton

Tags: java, chat

Can anyone suggest me how to insert smiley in jtextarea when clicking on  jbutton?

I have tried using jtable and then using selection listener on that table, but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) instead. Images can be inserted without having to override `paintComponent`. To emulate a single line "JTextField", you could use a `DocumentFilter` and prevent the insertion of newline characters.

Comment: +1, just use the insertIcon(...) method of the JTextPane.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple smileys, Create a `JTable` where you show each smiley in a cell, and add a `SelectionListener` or a `MouseListener` for each cell to detect which smiley was chosen and add it to the `JTextField`.

This approach makes your smileys easier to view than multiple buttons

Comment: can i insert image in jtable?

Comment: @puneetverma0711 of course you can :)